# Add Slider Input in Collapsable Sidebar Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to add a slider in a collapsible sidebar. I am having some issues  displaying the content that is associated with the tabName in the body. Ie. When I click the tab, the content in the body does not show.

This is the code and how it looks like when we comment out the slider input.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic Menu"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("hello", tabName = "helloWorld", icon = icon("calendar")#,
              #sliderInput("slide", "chose Slide", min = 5, max = 10, value = 10)
              )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "helloWorld",
              tags$h1("hey")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If we use the slider input, the body disappears. I have tried using some java script but I can not seem to get the result I am looking for. Keep in my the sidebar should be collapsible if I decide to add in another menuItem.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic Menu"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("hello", tabName = "helloWorld", icon = icon("calendar"),
              sliderInput("slide", "chose Slide", min = 5, max = 10, value = 10)
              )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "helloWorld",
              tags$h1("hey")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove `tabItems` and `tabItem` entirely of your Body?

Try with this:

```
dashboardBody(
    tags$h1("hey")
  )
```

Or do you want to have multiple bodies depending on which `menuItem` is selected?

Comment: Hi SeGa, I would like to have multiple bodies related to different menu tabs.

Comment: I dont think that is currently possible, as `menuItems` can only contain `menuSubItems`. If you put the slider in a `menuItem` the dashbaord doesn't know which item is selected or it will get the wrong one, if you put multiple `menuItems` in your `sidebarMenu`